# Creating event with Google Calendar fatal errors

Tags: php, events, google-calendar-api

I'm having a complete nightmare with this. I'm using the latest version of the PHP API from Github and just want to create events in a google calendar. There are tons of examples out there but many from a different version of the API where the calendar functions were in a contrib folder when now they're not. I've set everything up in the google developer console as guides state.

Using code I've found from a recent example here is what I'm using at the moment:

```
require_once './google-api/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once './google-api/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar");
$client->setClientId('#');
$client->setClientSecret('#');
$client->setRedirectUri('#');
$client->setDeveloperKey('#');
$calendar_id = "#";

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

if ($client->getAccessToken()){
echo "<hr><font size=+1>I have access to your calendar</font>";
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('Halloween');
$event->setLocation('The Neighbourhood');
$start = new Google_EventDateTime();
$start->setDateTime('2013-9-29T10:00:00.000-05:00');
$event->setStart($start);
$end = new Google_EventDateTime();
$end->setDateTime('2013-9-29T10:25:00.000-05:00');
$event->setEnd($end);
$createdEvent = $cal->events->insert($calendarid, $event);
echo "<br><font size=+1>Event created</font>";
}
```

But I keep getting this error PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Google_CalendarService' not found and the same for 'Google_Event' if I remove the CalendarService line.

The official documentation for this seems very inconsistent and inaccurate and so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the example at: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-query.php and then replacing the books service with the calendar service.

Answer (score 0):

`Google_CalendarService` should be `Google_Service_Calendar` based on the latest version in github.

I think `Google_Event` should be `Google_Service_Calendar_Event` as well.